# Entity-relationship model with one-to-many crossed relationships between entities. Is it wrong?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm modelling a database in which I have two crossed relationships. The model seems alright but I don't know how to translate it to a relational model, as there would be two relations referencing *recursively* (if thats the correct word).

[Entity-relationship model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5M9o.png) (I obviated the attributes as they do not provide useful information)

This is what it models: A being could give birth N times and at the same time, in a single birth multiple beings could have been born.

I know in a relational model a relation has to be defined before another can reference it, so I don't know how to solve this.

**Edit:** As *sqlvogel* correctly pointed out my model doesn't make much sense. For it to be practical the cardinality of have born in the side of Birth should be 0..1 so storing a first tier of beings "without parents" is allowed. This should also solve the problem with deferrable constraints, even if it's not in the most elegant way.

Comment: A definition is recursive when its parts define each other or themselves. Here we just have two simultaneous constraints. (FKs, which are called relationships, but aren't.) They refer to each other's tables. But there's no mutual/self definition. Eg if I said, tables T & U have to be equal, you wouldn't call that a recursive definition of a constraint, and it isn't a definition of the values, and even though you can't change one without the changing the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with a recursive design of this kind. In your particular example if your intention was to model *parentage* then it doesn't seem to make practical sense because (unless one "being" gives birth to itself) it would surely require an infinite number of births and beings in your database. On the other hand, your description suggests you are actually just modelling *births* rather than parentage, in which case your model may be a reasonable one.

Some DBMSs do allow you to create an entire schema in one go so you don't necessarily have to create one relation before another. Failing that, it should be possible to create the relations without referential constraints and then add the constraints afterwards.

If you are using a SQL DBMS there may be another potential problem when you come to use the tables you create. In standard SQL it's only possible to insert data or update data one table at a time. The standard way to populate two mutually dependent tables is to use the feature called "deferrable constraints", which means the constraints get evaluated at transaction commit time instead of at statement boundaries. Not all DBMSs support the deferrable constraints feature and many database designers prefer to avoid it.